# failing to load gem with native extensions: fresh 10.8, xcode 4.5, rvm

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

1. Clean Mountain Lion install
2. installed XCode 4.5 from the app store
3. installed the command-line tools
4. installed home brew
5. brew doctor is happy
6. installed RVM
7. rvm install 1.9.3

   - installer asked for more brews, installed the following:

     1. apple-gcc42
     2. autoconf
     3. automake
     4. libksba

install complete, everything looks good...

```
maximus:~$ gem install json
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/mmoser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
generator.c:369: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
generator.c:423: warning: unused parameter ‘self’
generator.c:759: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c:773: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c:773: warning: unused parameter ‘state’
generator.c:773: warning: unused parameter ‘obj’
generator.c:778: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c:778: warning: unused parameter ‘state’
generator.c:778: warning: unused parameter ‘obj’
generator.c:783: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c:783: warning: unused parameter ‘state’
generator.c:783: warning: unused parameter ‘obj’
generator.c:788: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c:788: warning: unused parameter ‘state’
generator.c:793: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
generator.c:793: warning: unused parameter ‘state’
generator.c:799: warning: unused parameter ‘Vstate’
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle

make install
/Users/mmoser/.rvm/scripts/install -c -m 0755 generator.bundle /Users/mmoser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/json-1.7.6/lib/json/ext
/Users/mmoser/.rvm/scripts/install: line 33: /Users/mmoser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/json-1.7.6/ext/json/ext/generator/scripts/functions/installer: No such file or directory
/Users/mmoser/.rvm/scripts/install: line 39: install_setup: command not found
Unrecognized option: -c
/Users/mmoser/.rvm/scripts/install: line 84: install_usage: command not found
make: *** [/Users/mmoser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/json-1.7.6/lib/json/ext/generator.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mmoser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/json-1.7.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mmoser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/json-1.7.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

I'm pulling my hair out. Can anyone explain this?

More info:

---

xcode

```
maximus:~$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

maximus:~$ la /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc* && la /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 12B Dec 24 19:22 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -> llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 32B Dec 24 19:22 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 32B Dec 24 19:22 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
```

---

/usr/bin

```
maximus:~$ la /usr/bin/gcc* && la /usr/bin/llvm-gcc*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 12B Jan 11 19:23 /usr/bin/gcc -> llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 12B Jan 11 19:23 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -> llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 32B Dec 25 08:24 /usr/bin/llvm-gcc -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 32B Jan 11 19:19 /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -> ../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
```

/usr/local/bin

```
maximus:~$ la /usr/local/bin/gcc* && la /usr/local/bin/llvm-gcc*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 mmoser admin 46B Jan 11 21:14 /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 -> ../Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2
ls: /usr/local/bin/llvm-gcc*: No such file or directory
```

---

versions

```
maximus:~$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

maximus:~$ gcc-4.2 --version
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

bash_profile contains (This is what is bringing in the $HOME/.rvm/* paths ?)

```
# Load RVM
if [ -f $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]; then
  source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
fi
```

---

current echo $PATH

```
/Users/mmoser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin
/Users/mmoser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/bin
/Users/mmoser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin
/Users/mmoser/.rvm/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/Users/mmoser
/Users/mmoser/scripts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you have `/Users/mmoser/.rvm/scripts/` in your `PATH`, this does not happen by accident - you had to add it manually, please remove it and install the gem again.

It is also required to reinstall ruby because `INSTALL` was recorded in ruby:

```
$ rvm config-get INSTALL
/usr/bin/install -c
```

So run:

```
rvm reinstall all
```

Comment: I alias my dot files in from my dropbox account, that path was 
a remnant from somethign else. Thank you for convincing me to 
clean up my PATH declorations, it was much needed ;) Alas,  my 
problem still persists. (current path added to question)

Comment: BAM! That was it, awesome sauce. Thank you so much.